# Get data on selection from MongoDb list in Python and HTML

Tags: html, mongodb, flask, python-3.9

I am developing a website in Python based on Flask framework ,using MongoDb .I have a list of medicine on one webpage and the next step i want to do is when I click on one of the medicine I should get detailed description of clicked(selected) medicine.

```
@app.route('/App_don')
def App_don():
    Approval_don = AppDonReq.find()
    print(Approval_don)
    return render_template('Approval_don_req.html', todos=Approval_don)
```

As per my understanding  I need to link these two python codes

```
@app.route('/Sel_App_don/<name>')
def Sel_App_don(name):
    if name:
        for item in name:
            print(item)
            return render_template('Approval_desc.html')
```

And below is my HTML code:

```
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" id="content">
                    <h2>List</h2>
                    <ul class="list-group t20">
                        {% for todo in todos %}
                        <a href="{{ url_for('App_don')}}">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                {{ todo.text }}
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whay exactly is you question?

Comment: I have a list of medicine that i have fetched from Mongodb,right now i only get the list now what i want is to get more detail regarding the selected medicine e.g stock,expiry on different wepage

Answer (score 0):

python:

```
@app.route('/')
def App_don():
    Approval_don = [{"text": "hallo"}]
    print(Approval_don)
    return render_template('blabla.html', todos=Approval_don)


@app.route('/Sel_App_don/<string:name>')
def Sel_App_don(name):
    if name:
        return render_template('new.html', var=name)
```

blabla.html:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" id="content">
                    <h2>List</h2>
                    <ul class="list-group t20">
                        {% for todo in todos %}
                        <form action = "/Sel_App_don/{{ todo.text }}">
                            <li class = "list-group-item"  >
                                <button type = "submit">{{todo.text}}</button>
                            </li >
                        </form >
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

new.html:

```
<h1> {{ var }} </h1>
```

When clicking on an element, it redirects the user to the new page with the argument from the specific column. These are examples you can customize them, they are just to showcase how it works.

Comment: Shall I add it to this html file or the other one?I tried this in mentioned html file that didn't worked

Comment: I do get the list but when i click on any element on the list it won't get redirected towards the description page

Comment: Hm, did you try the new one? Is there some error in the browser console or python console?

Comment: yes,I have added your new code but if you look carefully my python function aren't interlinked

Comment: Debugged it and updated to WORKING version. Finally! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231343/discussion-between-mandeep-m-and-jonas).